# How to fetch ics file on the client side in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, icalendar

I'm trying to fetch the online calendar (iCal) to the client side. From that calendar I want to fetch data like this: `(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}, __ob__: Observer]`. This is the example of a calendar: https://ical.neolab.hr/11111.ics. Is there any package that helps to read the data from ics of an already existing calendar?
Any recommendations how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure that ICS is really a thing on the web. At least, I only found a way to create it, not to input it thanks to this package: https://github.com/evildvl/vue-ICS

This package could be used when paired with some SSR (like Nuxt) apparently: https://github.com/Christop406/ical-parser

Otherwise, maybe trying to see how to "decode" the `.ics` extension may be a way. But there is no easy drag and drop API for this kind of extension as far as I know.

Comment: Could ical-parser package be helpful in my case? Would something like this work: ```fs.readFileSync("https://ical.neolab.hr/11111.ics", "utf-8");``` ?

Comment: @JanTuđan in pure Vue, you don't have access to Node environment so you cannot read any file with `fs`. Hence you need something like Nuxt with SSR capabilities to proceed. You can check some of my answers here if you'd like: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A8816585+fs